# The reason codes from BigQueryError.getError()

Tags: google-bigquery

Do we have a list of possible reason codes from BigQueryError.getReason() https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/index.html?com/google/cloud/bigquery/package-summary.html ?

BigQueryError is a java class from Google's BigQuery client lib.

We are streaming inserting rows to BigQuery. Would like to know under what kind of reason codes, we can retry the insertion.

Thanks

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors

Answer (score 1):

You can find the BigQuery error codes in the following page

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors

One important point for HTTP errors from the documentation (not listed in the doc)

> If you receive an HTTP response code that doesn't appear in the list
>   below, the response code indicates an issue or an expected result with
>   the HTTP request. For example, a 502 error indicates there is an issue
>   with your network connection. For a full list of HTTP response codes,
>   see HTTP response codes.

Comment: BigQueryError.getReason() does not return the error codes in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors. So far I have seen one reason code from BigQueryError.getReason() that is 'timeout'.

Comment: like i said. some general http errors are not listed. You can refer those here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes